# Email link doesn't work properly after # sign

Tags: coldfusion

I have a simple link that opens a email.
When I open the email in IE it seems if the address has a "#" sign it doesnt show what ever is after the sign and it only happens in IE.

For example is the address is : 1234 santa cruz #123 st avenue 
So after the # sign it wont show anything after .

Any ideas on why its happening and how to fix it?

```
 <a href="mailto:test@test.org?subject=Update
  &body=
  Account: #trim(Account)#%0d
  Address: #trim(Address1)#, #trim(comments)# %0d  "> (Request Update) </a>
  </cfif>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: @MattBusche if you mean #address1# look like, it shows fine, no errors , its just when i click to open the email link

Comment: Can you post the full html link do we can debug the issue?

Comment: @MattBusche i made a sample here  https://jsfiddle.net/bcsxhzgk/

Comment: Um, that's not the generated HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `URLEncodedFormat()` function, to fix these kind of issues while working with URLs. The following code will fix your issue.

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.org?subject=Update
&body=
Account: #trim(URLEncodedFormat(Account))#%0d
Address: #trim(URLEncodedFormat(Address1))#, #trim(URLEncodedFormat(comments))# %0d"> (Request Update) </a>
```

Comment: This is the right answer but the entire "body" variable should be enclosed in a URLEncodedFormat().  Example &body=#URLEncodedFormat("Account: #trim(Account)#%0d
  Address: #trim(Address1)#, #trim(comments)# %0d")#

Comment: Isn't `URLEncodedFormat` deprecated in favor of `EncodeForURL`?